# visual studio 2008 MFC linker error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc

i start a mfc application with a dialog window  i debug it (nothing added) and i give me an linker error 
i run it on release mod and it worked

my OS is windows 7

what should i do

error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IncrBuildImage
1>  Version 9.00.21022.08
1>  ExceptionCode            = C0000005
1>  ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
1>  ExceptionAddress         = 00E7FCF7 (00E00000) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\link.exe"
1>  NumberParameters         = 00000002
1>  ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 00000000
1>  ExceptionInformation[ 1] = 00D1D670
1>CONTEXT:
1>  Eax    = 400BCC58  Esp    = 0034ECB4
1>  Ebx    = 40008164  Ebp    = 0034ECDC
1>  Ecx    = 00D1D670  Esi    = 400BCAEC
1>  Edx    = 0034ECCC  Edi    = 00E0D6C0
1>  Eip    = 00E7FCF7  EFlags = 00010246
1>  SegCs  = 00000023  SegDs  = 0000002B
1>  SegSs  = 0000002B  SegEs  = 0000002B
1>  SegFs  = 00000053  SegGs  = 0000002B
1>  Dr0    = 00000000  Dr3    = 00000000
1>  Dr1    = 00000000  Dr6    = 00000000
1>  Dr2    = 00000000  Dr7    = 00000000
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\arda\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\1234\1234\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>1234 - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post the specific error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IncrBuildImage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001289/how-to-resolve-fatal-error-lnk1000-internal-error-during-incrbuildimage)

Answer (score 2):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB948127

Answer (score 1):

A full rebuild of the debug configuration.  Sometimes developer studio just gets itself confused.  If that doesn't work, quit devstudio, delete all the .suo, .ncb and .ilk files then try another rebuild.