# How to resolve fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IncrBuildImage?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, compilation

I am trying to recompile solution file for [memcached project](http://www.splinedancer.com/memcached-win32/) on Windows 7 64 bit with Visual Studio 2008 and got the following error:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IncrBuildImage
1>  Version 9.00.21022.08
1>  ExceptionCode            = C0000005
1>  ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
1>  ExceptionAddress         = 001FFCF7 (00180000) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\link.exe"
1>  NumberParameters         = 00000002
1>  ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 00000000
1>  ExceptionInformation[ 1] = 011BD670
1>CONTEXT:
1>  Eax    = 400DA210  Esp    = 0014EADC
1>  Ebx    = 4000815C  Ebp    = 0014EB04
1>  Ecx    = 011BD670  Esi    = 400DA098
1>  Edx    = 0014EAF4  Edi    = 0018D6C0
1>  Eip    = 001FFCF7  EFlags = 00010246
1>  SegCs  = 00000023  SegDs  = 0000002B
1>  SegSs  = 0000002B  SegEs  = 0000002B
1>  SegFs  = 00000053  SegGs  = 0000002B
1>  Dr0    = 00000000  Dr3    = 00000000
1>  Dr1    = 00000000  Dr6    = 00000000
1>  Dr2    = 00000000  Dr7    = 00000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Windows SDK 7 for 64 bit platform resolved my problem. I simply didn't have it when I've tried to compile without it.  My bad.

Answer (score 21):

This is a bug in the linker. It may be the same as [this problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948127). Try installing [VS2008 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en) if you don't have it as it contains that fix and others.

If this doesn't help, turning off incremental linking may be a workaround.

Comment: that's it indeed, had the same problem but the hotfix fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. Without setup a new hotfix I've found a very easy solution. 
To link a new solution I proceed in this way:
   1) Compiling the file cpp (CTRL-F7)
   2) Generating the solution (F7)

All the times the problem has disappeared

Answer (score 1):

Turning off incremental linking didn't work for me because I was developing a static library and therefore instead of the Linker properties I had a Librarian.

So I found one more way to fix this:

`Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Optimization -> Whole program optimization`

switch to "**No**".

It helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error.  After trying many cleans and rebuilds I went for the more nuclear option.

1. Deleted the entire source tree.
2. Did a full get from TFS
3. Restarted the computer
4. Compiled.

Could work for others, seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when compiling an [unreal-engine4](/questions/tagged/unreal-engine4) v4.23 game on Windows 10 with VS 2017 Community Edition. The solution was just to update to the latest version of [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio), as the subsequent patches included a fix for this. I am currently at v15.9.18 and it's compiling without this error.

No need to reboot or install any particular hotfixes, just the standard updates.