# MFC DLL using C++ with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, dllexport

I can't seem to find any walk-trough on how to create a MFC DLL using Visual Studio 2008. My problem is the following. I need to use wininet.h with my DLL and my solution to that was to use MFC DLL. Anyhow trying to link my project gives me [5 Link errors](http://intrastudent.se/questions/BuildLog7310.htm)
I believe that the error is of a kind that I need to add Additional Library Directories. But which one should I add?

```
void ClearHandles(void) //close all open handlers if any
```

```
void SetClientCert(void) //try to set a cert if possible
```

```
void FindCertWithOUNITName(void) //This function performs a certificate contex search
```

All help would be appreciated!
I would even appreciate links to tutorials or walk-throughs using a DLL with MFC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add Crypt32.lib to your lib dependencies under Linker/Input - Additional dependencies:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much... I've got it working now. The picture was great and easy to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add crypt32.lib to your list of dependencies for the DLL.  You can find this in the MSDN page for the API, for example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376026(VS.85).aspx).

> Requirements
>
> Minimum supported client
> Windows 2000 Professional
>
> Minimum
> supported server
> Windows 2000 Server
>
> Header
> Wincrypt.h
>
> Library
> Crypt32.lib
>
> DLL
> Crypt32.dll

Comment: @Java Dude - do you have VS2008 SP1?  See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001289/how-to-resolve-fatal-error-lnk1000-internal-error-during-incrbuildimage

Comment: thank you very much... I've got it working now. Your information was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The Linker IncrBuildImage error is described here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/801ba6d7-a284-4b5d-a75b-3652138d6dff

Perhaps the hotfix would help