# fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IncrBuildImage

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc

I got this strange error when build a new MFC application, i just make a new MFC Application i didn't change anything in the generated form, how to fix this error please?

```
1>Linking...
1>Embedding manifest...
1>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IncrBuildImage
1>  Version 9.00.21022.08
1>  ExceptionCode            = C0000005
1>  ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
1>  ExceptionAddress         = FEA4C880
1>  NumberParameters         = 00000002
1>  ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 00000008
1>  ExceptionInformation[ 1] = FEA4C880
1>CONTEXT:
1>  Eax    = FEA4C880  Esp    = 002DEF08
1>  Ebx    = 400081C8  Ebp    = 002DEF34
1>  Ecx    = 0097D670  Esi    = 405B8CFC
1>  Edx    = 002DEF24  Edi    = 0006D6C0
1>  Eip    = FEA4C880  EFlags = 00010246
1>  SegCs  = 0000001B  SegDs  = 00000023
1>  SegSs  = 00000023  SegEs  = 00000023
1>  SegFs  = 0000003B  SegGs  = 00000000
1>  Dr0    = 00000000  Dr3    = 00000000
1>  Dr1    = 00000000  Dr6    = 00000000
1>  Dr2    = 00000000  Dr7    = 00000000
1>Build log was saved at     "file://c:\Users\Yasmine\Desktop\Calculator\Calculator\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>Calculator - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IncrBuildImage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001289/how-to-resolve-fatal-error-lnk1000-internal-error-during-incrbuildimage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fix will help your problem... http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB948127

Comment: Broken link, current article is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948127 actual download is here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=11399

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a full re-build. That normally sorts this sort of thing out.