# VS 2013 Link1000

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I try to compile a realy big project with VS 2013 using the platformtoolset VS 2008 (v90). 
I have to use this platformtoolset because the project was developed with VS2008.

I already fixed some common issues when using this specific VS but the current error keeps me wondering.
All libs have been created sucessfully but it seems like the linker has got issues with the .exe ...

The full errorlog (please notice the link.exe does also crash with 'Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker doesn't work anymore').

```
16>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
16>  
16>  
16>  
16>LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IncrBuildImage
16>  
16>    Version 9.00.21022.08
16>  
16>    ExceptionCode            = C0000005
16>    ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
16>    ExceptionAddress         = 0118FCF7 (01110000) "F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\link.exe"
16>    NumberParameters         = 00000002
16>    ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 00000000
16>    ExceptionInformation[ 1] = 00F9D670
16>  
16>  CONTEXT:
16>    Eax    = 41D3CC40  Esp    = 003FEFB4
16>    Ebx    = 40008178  Ebp    = 003FEFDC
16>    Ecx    = 00F9D670  Esi    = 41D3CAC0
16>    Edx    = 003FEFCC  Edi    = 0111D6C0
16>    Eip    = 0118FCF7  EFlags = 00010246
16>    SegCs  = 00000023  SegDs  = 0000002B
16>    SegSs  = 0000002B  SegEs  = 0000002B
16>    SegFs  = 00000053  SegGs  = 0000002B
16>    Dr0    = 00000000  Dr3    = 00000000
16>    Dr1    = 00000000  Dr6    = 00000000
16>    Dr2    = 00000000  Dr7    = 00000000
========== Alles neu erstellen: 15 erfolgreich, 1 fehlerhaft, 0 übersprungen ==========
```

Last line is in german (i am using german VS). Meaning 'Everything created new: 15 successful, 1 defective, 0 jumped...

I found this 'fix' in the internet but the server seems offline for me...
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB948127

Maybe someone else has an idea how to fix the issue?

Comment: Fixed: I installed the Windows7 SDK and recompiled the project, That fixed my issue :) (Notice to me: don't ask questions when you still have options ...)

Comment: It happens, incremental linking in the VS2008 linker was a bit buggy.  Just use Build > Clean so it can start with a fresh copy.  Updating the SDK is the long way around to forcing it to recompile everything.  Hehe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IncrBuildImage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001289/how-to-resolve-fatal-error-lnk1000-internal-error-during-incrbuildimage)